# search term with hyphens are not searchable in sharepoint 2013

Tags: search, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a search application which basically provides search services. Technically it uses SharePoint 2013 for search functionality and display the results using UI technologies. Here we have a Textbox a user can enter the search term, perform search and get the results from the SharePoint API. But the issue here his we are unable to do search the links that contains hyphens.

Example : 
Scenario 1: when user texts this link in the textbox "https://cis.somedomain.com/about/pages/quality-and-risk-management.aspx" and perform search, they cannot get the search results from the SharePoint 2013.

Scenario 2 : when user texts this link in the textbox "https://cis.somedomain.com/rr/pages/assurance_sas.aspx" and perform search, they are able to get the results.

Problem : if the link contains hyphens search results are not appearing , but search results are appearing if the link contains uderscore.

Is this the limitation of the SharePoint ? do we have any configurable solution, Please help me out on this one. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge sharepoint does not have such a limitation. If I understand you correctly, when a user performs a search for a page which has a hyphen in the URL, results do not show,  however if a search is performed on a page with an underscore in the URL, the results are shown? Do you have any search result sources that could be affecting what results are shown based on the search text?